# Weight Converter GUI, press button code creation?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a new to programming and this is my second project, so i wanna build a simple weight converter GUI, LBS to KG // KG to LBS

This is what the GUI look like : 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrVHg.jpg
[image]
the problem is: When I write the number to get converted on the "Enter Amount" then  check the Checkbotton "LBS to KG" my program automatically insert the Converted weight answer on the "Weigh" box.

I want to Check "LBS to KG" then click on the Calculate Botton and then the program Insert the answer on the "Weight" Box.

I searched a lot online and I didn't find the answer.

```
enter code here
from tkinter import *


main = Tk()
main.title("Weight Converter")
main.geometry("500x100")

#Calculation
def mult():
     blank.delete(0, END)
     ans = int(weight1.get()) * 0.45
     blank.insert(0, ans)


def mult1():
    blank.delete(0, END)
    ans = int(weight1.get()) / 0.45
    blank.insert(0, ans)




#Text
Label(main, text = "Enter Amount: ").grid(row=1)
Label(main, text = "      Weight: ").grid(row=2)
#Entry
weight1 = Entry(main)
blank = Entry(main)

weight1.grid(row=1, column=1)
blank.grid(row=2, column=1)

#Checkbutton
v = IntVar()
v1 = IntVar()
c = Checkbutton(main, text="Lbs to KG", command=mult, variable=v).grid(row=1, column=5)
c1 = Checkbutton(main, text="KG to LBs", command=mult1, variable=v1).grid(row=2, column=5)

Button(main, text="Calculate").grid(row=4, column=1)






main.mainloop()
```

Comment: @stovfl i know, but even if I define a command to the button it wont work cause i dont know how to link the "If the LBs to KG" Chekbox is check to the button.

Comment: @stovfl ok thank you i will  try it

Comment: @stovfl i didn"t find the solution, do you have a example of code that will match with my code?

Comment: @stovfl Ok thank you it i found the problem. have a great day